# How to interpret a Labor Condition Application (LCA) Posting Notice during the stay-at-home quarantine?

Tags: privacy, immigration

My colleague is now, like many of us, working from home due to the coronavirus. We're in NYC.

She's also been applying for an H-1B though and received the following letter, which seems to say that she must post her employment details in a public area of her apartment building. But her building has somewhere between 50-100 residents. Understandably she's not comfortable exposing her apartment number plus name and employer and other details to all these strangers.

Are we misunderstanding the notice? Is there an alternative, especially since we normally work from an office? If no alternative, would it be acceptable to post at two locations on her floor rather than the apartment's lobby?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any indication that it has to be posted in a public area?  It seems to me that she could satisfy the requirements by posting one copy in her bedroom and the other in her kitchen.  At the very least, she could ask them whether this would be acceptable.

Comment: Hm, I guess, I had trouble seeing what the point of posting inside a home is then? And also because they say "conspicuous" and I don't know what they mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Global Mobility Specialist" of my company has confirmed in a Slack channel for immigration information that it's fine to post this inside your own apartment, e.g. living room and kitchen. He said some folks even post it in their bedroom.